# CSS and HTML 4.0 errors causing blank spaces in rich text method(QT)

Tags: html, css, validation, w3c

There is a method called drawRichText where is a input parameter 'option' containing string text. The bag is caused by string "]]>ibroketheconfig". The Qt translate it to HTML 4.0 strict. I need to solve this bug. There are several error on validator [W3](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input), but on the others it seems to be working.

[HTML and CSS code causing blank field.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmnYN.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-html40/strict.dtd"> 
<html>
   <head>
      <meta name="qrichtext" content="1" />
      <style type="text/css">     p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }     </style>
   </head>
   <body style=" font-family:'Segoe UI'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;">
       
      <p style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;">]]&gt;ibroketheconfig</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

```
int DItemDelegate::drawRichText(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option)
{
    DTextDocument textDocument;
    textDocument.setDefaultFont(option.font);
    textDocument.setExtendedHtml(option.text);
    textDocument.setDocumentMargin(0.0);

    // Nastaveni barvy textu podle Qt::ForegroundRole
    QTextCharFormat format;
    format.setForeground(getTextColor(option));
    QTextBlockFormat textBlockFormat;
    textBlockFormat.setAlignment(option.displayAlignment);

    textDocument.setTextWidth(-1);
    qreal idealTextWidth = textDocument.idealWidth();

    if ((option.displayAlignment.testFlag(Qt::AlignRight) || option.displayAlignment.testFlag(Qt::AlignHCenter))
            && idealTextWidth < option.rect.width()) // posledni podminka kontroluje, zda vubec ma smysl uvazovat alignment textu
    {
        // nastavime sirku kresleneho textu (jinak nebude fungovat alignment)
        textDocument.setTextWidth(option.rect.width());
    }

    QTextCursor cursor(&textDocument);
    cursor.select(QTextCursor::Document);
    cursor.mergeCharFormat(format);
    cursor.select(QTextCursor::Document);
    cursor.mergeBlockFormat(textBlockFormat);

    if (option.rect.width() > 0)
    {
        painter->save();
        QRect clip(0, 0, option.rect.width(), option.rect.height());
        qreal idealWidth = textDocument.idealWidth();
        if (idealWidth > option.rect.width())
        {
            QString additionalText("...");
            painter->setPen(getTextColor(option));
            painter->drawText(clip, Qt::AlignRight, additionalText);

            // Orez nevejduvsiho se textu provest na sirku "..." od praveho okraje vykreslovaci oblasti
            // aby nedoslo k jeho prekryti naslednym obsahem radku
            QFontMetrics fontMetrics(textDocument.defaultFont());
            clip.setWidth(option.rect.width() - fontMetrics.width(additionalText));
        }

        if (option.rect.height() > textDocument.size().height())
        {
            if (option.displayAlignment.testFlag(Qt::AlignVCenter))
            {
                painter->translate(0, (option.rect.height() - textDocument.size().height()) / 2.0);
            }
            else if (option.displayAlignment.testFlag(Qt::AlignBottom))
            {
                painter->translate(0, option.rect.height() - textDocument.size().height());
            }
        }

        textDocument.drawContents(painter, clip);
        painter->restore();
    }

    return idealTextWidth;
}
```